# Tableau Multiple IF Statements

Tags: tableau-desktop

I am trying to write an IF statement but am getting 1 error - any help would be greatly appreciated.

I need the statement to say: If Prepared Date is after Prepared Deadline, then return the number of days between the 2 dates. If Prepared Date is before or equal to Prepared Deadline, then return "0", Also, if Prepared Date is null, return return the number of days between Preparer Deadline and the current date.

if [Prepared Date] > [Prep Deadline] then datediff('day',[Prep Deadline],[Prepared Date])
elseif [Prepared Date] <= [Prep Deadline] then "0"
elseif ISNULL([Prepared Date]) then datediff('day',[Prep Deadline],TODAY())
end

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHvWP.png)

Answer (score 1):

Two errors are clear. The first is described in the error message. Don’t mix strings and ints, so lose the quotes around zero to turn it into an int. The second is you should test for null values in a field first, before using it in an expression. Lastly, since if/else if tests are evaluated in sequence, you don’t need to repeat the comparison on the third branch - you can just use an else.

So I’d try

```
if isnull([Prepared Date]) then
  datediff('day',[Prep Deadline],today()) 
elseif [Prepared Date] > [Prep Deadline] then
  datediff('day',[Prep Deadline],[Prepared Date])
else
  0
end
```

You can simplify further by using the IFNULL() function to supply a default value in  situations where a field is null, and the MAX() function to make sure you never return negative numbers.

```
max(datediff('day',[Prep Deadline], ifnull([Prepared Date], today())), 0)
```

Its a matter of taste which you prefer -- logically both expressions are equivalent.